# udevadm test command on Ubuntu gives warnings not seen in Manjaro

Tags: networking, usb, mount, udev, inotify

I created a very simply udev rule `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules` that runs a script to create a file in /tmp when a USB key is inserted into my computer. I tested this on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu Server 20.04 and on a Dell Inspiron running Manjaro. In both cases the rule fires and the file is created.

So maybe this isn't a problem but I am curious about the output of the command:
`sudo udevadm test /sys/class/block/sda1`

When I run this command on both OSs I get mostly the same output but in the case of Ubuntu I get two warnings::

1. *Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel command line, ignoring.* [Possibly this issue?](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=762101)
2. *Invalid inotify descriptor.* [Possibly this issue?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1465913)

**Ubuntu**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/default$ sudo udevadm test /sys/class/block/sda1 
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program 
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because 
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run. 
 
Load module index 
Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel command line, ignoring. 
Parsed configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link 
Parsed configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/network/73-usb-net-by-mac.link 
Created link configuration context. 
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/01-md-raid-creating.rules 
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules 
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/40-vm-hotadd.rules 
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-apport.rules 
...
...
...
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/96-e2scrub.rules 
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules 
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules 
Invalid inotify descriptor. 
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 
DEVNAME=/dev/sda1 
DEVTYPE=partition 
PARTN=1 
PARTNAME=Main Data Partition 
MAJOR=8 
MINOR=1 
ACTION=add 
SUBSYSTEM=block 
ID_SCSI=1 
ID_SCSI_INQUIRY=1 
ID_VENDOR=Lexar
...
...
...
ID_FS_TYPE_NEW=vfat 
TAGS=:systemd: 
USEC_INITIALIZED=10879865388 
run: '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sda1' 
run: '/usr/local/bin/test_script2.sh' 
Unload module index 
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

I don't get these warnings in Manjaro and also can see some more helpful output as it explicitly lists output where I can correlate my udev rule being processed to the device block of the USB key being attached.

**Manjaro**

```
[flex-inspiron7520 tmp]# udevadm test /sys/class/block/sdb1 
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program 
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because 
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run. 
 
Trying to open "/etc/systemd/hwdb/hwdb.bin"... 
Trying to open "/etc/udev/hwdb.bin"... 
Trying to open "/usr/lib/systemd/hwdb/hwdb.bin"... 
Trying to open "/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.bin"... 
=== trie on-disk === 
tool version:          250 
file size:        11819111 bytes 
header size             80 bytes 
strings            2415199 bytes 
nodes              9403832 bytes 
Load module index 
Found cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/, full unified hierarchy 
Found container virtualization none. 
Loaded timestamp for '/etc/systemd/network'. 
Loaded timestamp for '/usr/lib/systemd/network'. 
Parsed configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link 
Created link configuration context. 
Loaded timestamp for '/etc/udev/rules.d'. 
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/01-md-raid-creating.rules 
...
...
...
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules 
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules 
sdb1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:71 GROUP 995 
sdb1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:69 LINK 'disk/by-id/usb-Lexar_JD_FireFly_<< redacted >>' 
sdb1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:93 LINK 'disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1' 
sdb1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:110 Importing properties from results of builtin command 'blkid' 
sdb1: Probe /dev/sdb1 with raid and offset=0 
sdb1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:113 LINK 'disk/by-uuid/<< redacted >>' 
sdb1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:114 LINK 'disk/by-label/RESCUE' 
sdb1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:121 LINK 'disk/by-partuuid/<< redacted >>' 
sdb1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:122 LINK 'disk/by-partlabel/Main\x20Data\x20Partition' 
sdb1: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules:3 RUN '/usr/local/bin/test_script.sh' 
sdb1: Preserve permissions of /dev/sdb1, uid=0, gid=995, mode=0660 
sdb1: Handling device node '/dev/sdb1', devnum=b8:17 
sdb1: sd-device: Created db file '/run/udev/data/b8:17' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/host6/target6:0:
0/6:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1' 
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 
DEVNAME=/dev/sdb1 
DEVTYPE=partition 
DISKSEQ=16 
PARTN=1 
PARTNAME=Main Data Partition 
MAJOR=8 
MINOR=17 
ACTION=add 
SUBSYSTEM=block 
TAGS=:systemd: 
ID_VENDOR=Lexar
...
...
...
CURRENT_TAGS=:systemd: 
USEC_INITIALIZED=5699747586 
run: '/usr/local/bin/test_script.sh' 
Unload module index 
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

**My Distros**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/default$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1059-raspi #67-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 11 14:16:01 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

and...

```
[flex@flex-inspiron7520 bin]$ uname -a
Linux flex-inspiron7520 5.15.32-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 28 09:16:36 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**My Questions:**
Do I need to be concerned about the errors/warnings in the udevadm test ... output in Ubuntu? Might this stop udev rules from working properly on Ubuntu?
Does anyone know how to fix these errors so I can see the full output same as what I get in Manjaro?

Cheers!

### Additional Information

(I added the backslashes for readability)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/cmdline
coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 \
snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=0 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=0 \
bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=<< Redacted >> \ 
vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000 \ 
elevator=deadline net.ifnames=0 console=ttyS0,115200 \ 
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable \ 
rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc quiet splash quiet splash
```

After reading again this [debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=762101) I tried enabling persistent (?predictable) interface names on my Ubuntu 20.04. Since it is running on a Pi 4 I had to cmdline.txt in the boot partition:
`sudo nano /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`
.. and changed `net.ifnames=0` to `net.ifnames=1` then rebooted. Now when I run the command `sudo udevadm test /sys/class/block/sda1` I get the exact same output as I did before on Ubuntu just minus the message: `Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel command line, ignoring.` So now I don't know if that was a problem to worry about or not.

I suppose the reason for the differences in the first few lines of `udevadm` output between Ubuntu vs Manjaro is in part due not only to the command running on two different systems but also the version of the udev/udevadm software is different on each OS. Manjaro (250) vs Ubuntu (245).

Comment: In Ubuntu please `cat /proc/cmdline`

Comment: @nobody Thank you! OK, I see where you are going with this. So do I just edit `/proc/cmdline` and change `net.ifnames=1` to "opt-in to persistent interface naming". I don't really know what that's all about. Is it safe for me to enable "persistent interface naming"?

As to the `Invalid inotify descriptor` message. Any ideas why I get that message in Ubuntu but not in Manjaro?

Comment: Nope. I get the same message on Ubuntu. I make the renaming from my net interfaces somehow over udev rule

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my Raspberry Pi 4 to the latest (April 2022) version of Ubuntu Server 22.04 and I no longer see the `Invalid inotify descriptor` message in the output of the `udevadm test` command.

Ubuntu Server 20.04 (for Raspberry Pi at least) contains Systemd v245 but Ubuntu Server 22.04 for Raspberry Pi contains Systemd v249.11. Manjaro 21.2.5 has Systemd v250.

So I guess the difference in output from the `udevadm test` command between Ubuntu Server 20.04 and Manjaro 21.2.5 is due to the different versions of systemd in each distro.

I would still like to understand WHY I was getting the `invalid inotify descriptor` message on Ubuntu Server 20.04 on the Raspberry Pi but for now the solution was to upgrade to Ubuntu Server 22.04.